# Find the top n values per row in one data frame, and use these indices to obtain values in another data frame to perform a pair-wise operation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

In this case, I have two data frames A and B.

```
      c1  c2   c3              c1      c2     c3 
r0    7    6    4       r0      0       0      1
r1    6    2    5       r1      1       1      0
r2    3    5    9       r2      1       0      1
```

A is the data frame on the left, and B on the right.

Basically my goal is to find the top 2 values in each row of A, and the corresponding row values in B, and then take the sum of the products of these pairs.

So for example in the first row, the top values in A are 7, and 6, which correspond to 0, 0 in the first row of B. I then want to return 7 * 0 + 6 * 0 = 0. I'd like to do this over every row and return something like:

```
d1   0
d2   6
d3   9
```

I'm currently using an implementation with using numpy argsort to find the index of the top n values in each row of A, and then using a map and a self-defined function to go over rows and find the product-sum.

This method has ended up being really slow for me, so I was wondering if there are any faster alternatives. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) to get top 2 values and use that as mask for `B`.

```
In [1311]: (A*B.where(A.rank(axis=1) >= 2)).sum(axis=1)
Out[1311]:
r0    0.0
r1    6.0
r2    9.0
dtype: float64
```

---

Details

```
In [1314]: A.rank(axis=1)
Out[1314]:
     c1   c2   c3
r0  3.0  2.0  1.0
r1  3.0  1.0  2.0
r2  1.0  2.0  3.0

In [1315]: A.rank(axis=1) >=2
Out[1315]:
       c1     c2     c3
r0   True   True  False
r1   True  False   True
r2  False   True   True

In [1317]: B.where(A.rank(axis=1) >= 2)
Out[1317]:
     c1   c2   c3
r0  0.0  0.0  NaN
r1  1.0  NaN  0.0
r2  NaN  0.0  1.0

In [1318]: (A*B.where(A.rank(axis=1) >= 2))
Out[1318]:
     c1   c2   c3
r0  0.0  0.0  NaN
r1  6.0  NaN  0.0
r2  NaN  0.0  9.0
```

Comment: Worked just as expected and it was much faster than my implementation. Thanks for the help!

Comment: As a followup, if rather than the sum I want to pass each row of A and B into a function, what would be the best way to do it? As in after doing the masking, I want something like myfunc(Arow, Brow) to run on every row of A and its corresponding row in B.